# Calling a function iteratively inside a div from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a task for which on every click of the button some text is added or updated in the same div.

I have created a dummy code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        console.log("functionCalled");
        var num = $("#numChange").text();
        var numInc = num + "1";

        var output = "<b>Hello world!</b><button id='btn2'>Set HTML</button><p id='numChange'>" + numInc + "</p>"
        $("#changeMe").html(output);
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<div id="changeMe">

<button id='btn2'>Set HTML</button>
<p id='numChange'>1</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On one click of button, the text changes from 1 to 11, but nothing happens on second click and henceforth. I want it to keep changing everytime I click the button, i.e. it should change to 111, then next click 1111 and so on.

I am not able to figure out whats wrong or missing in the code

Comment: You need to delegate: Change `$("#btn2").click(....` to `$("#changeMe").on("click","#btn2",function...`

Comment: OR better: Do NOT change the button:  `$("#btn2").click(function(){
        console.log("functionCalled");
        var num = $("#numChange").text();
        var numInc = num + "1";

$("#numChange").text(numInc);
    });`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This was very helpful :)

Comment: @mplungjan after you posted the link, i also think this is a duplicate, but I am not deleting the question as someone else might look through this and may be helpful for them.

Comment: It is really, really not worth keeping. There are thousands of identical questions. See the list I made in 10 seconds. And now it cannot be deleted because it has an accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time the button on which you are attaching the `click` event is present in the document. That's why the button click works as expected. But the button created dynamically does not have the event attached to it.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically created element to work as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#btn2',function(){
        console.log("functionCalled");
        var num = $("#numChange").text();
        var numInc = num + "1";

        var output = "<b>Hello world!</b><button id='btn2'>Set HTML</button><p id='numChange'>" + numInc + "</p>"
        $("#changeMe").html(output);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<div id="changeMe">

<button id='btn2'>Set HTML</button>
<p id='numChange'>1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: With 10k you could easily close as the dupe it is - also delegate to the closer  $("#changeMe")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace html just modify the button's text

```
var num = $("#numChange").text() + "1";
$("#numChange").text(numInc);
```